# What are the features on X-37 fairing/transport jig

Tags: x-37, identify-this-object

Is the structure on the bottom side of the X-37 in this photo a launch fairing or a transport jig?  In either case, what are the arrays of transparent-looking round things on it?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's the launch fairing (the other half is visible on the right). The silvery panels are used for noise reduction; they contain [Helmholz absorbers](http://www.arianespace.com/news-mission-update/2003/112.asp), cavities tuned to [absorb a single frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_resonance). Each round object contains the opening of a cavity.

Without protection, the noise level during launch is loud enough to damage the payload. The absorbers reduce the noise in the fairing just enough to make sure there's no damage.

A Helmholz resonator has a single resonance frequency. If sound at that exact frequency enters the resonator, you can get the cavity to absorb some of that energy (up to 60%) as heat. So a Helmholz absorber is a resonator [modified](http://www.hunecke.de/en/knowledge/absorbers/helmholtz-resonators.html) to create a high viscous resistance at the neck.

[According to a](http://www.bbc.co.uk/rd/publications/rdreport_1949_29) BBC research paper on the subject:

> ...Under ideal conditions, (infinite rigidity of container etc. ),
>   absorption of energy can be considered to take place entirely in the
>   resistance at the neck. This resistance has two components, the
>   viscous resistance of the air in the neck, and the radiation
>   resistance, the latter being much the smaller component in the case of
>   narrow necks. The viscous resistance is dependent on the dimensions
>   of the neck and is influenced by the presence of resistive material.

[Thesis on the subject (110 pages)](http://preserve.lehigh.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2015&context=etd)

Comment: ...but what for?

Comment: Noise reduction. I've added a bit more explanation.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about Helmholtz resonance!

Comment: @Erik On Ariane V fairing   https://twitter.com/ArianeGroup/status/1473943597007388691