# What are these 'Lego' plates inside the Atlas 5 fairing?

Tags: spacecraft, atlas-v, fairings, identify-this-object

My local engineering newspaper has an article on the X-37B craft, with an image displaying the craft within half of the shell that encapsulates it. The shell has a number of plates arranged on its inside surface, which look decidedly like silvery 'Lego' base plates:

[image]

What are those plates for?

The image is captioned:

> This is how the X-37B is encapsulated at the top of an Atlas 5 rocket from the Cape Canaveral Cape Canaveral launch site in Florida. Photo: U.S. Air Force courtesy photo Photo: U.S. Air Force courtesy photo.

Answer (score 2):

As detailed in [this other answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/9070/19586), they provide noise dampening.

Thanks to Hobbes who is possibly a Helmholtz nut. ;)

(...gotta wait 2 days before I can close this question...)

Comment: maybe you can accept your own answer?

Comment: ....yes, in 21 hours...