# What is or are the official English names for the eventual space station being built by China, and of the first module that's in orbit now?

Tags: space-station, china, cnsa

China has launched the first module of a space station and plans to have astronauts inside it to start woking in about a month.

In Astronomy SE they've already started calling it the "Chinese Space Station" or "CSS"

- [This answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43709/7982) to *Details on the telescope(s) on the Chinese Space Station 天和*
- and there's a [`csst` tag](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csst) for the CSS Telescope

To my surprise and chagrin, publications by Chinese academics do cite this kind of naming (e.g. CSS-OS and CSST)

- [Cosmology from the Chinese Space Station Optical Survey (CSS-OS)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.04634)
- [Testing photometric redshift measurements with filter definition of the Chinese Space Station Optical Survey (CSS-OS)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09586)

**Question:** In the west, are there official names for the final space station and the current module?

Comment: It surprises me that apparently there is a need for an English alternative name for the Chinese space vehicles, yet everyone seemed fine with romanizing the Russian ones…

Comment: @Ludo :-) I think that *Tiangong*, the romanization of *Tiāngōng* which is [Hanyu Pinyin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin) for 天宫 is just fine and asking this question doesn't mean I think differently. (see [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37132/#comment118126_37132) for example) The goal of on-topic Stack Exchange questions is simply the generation of good answers for future readers. What inspired this question was the Chinese scientists referring to Tiangong as "The Chinese Space Station" or CSS. I just wanted to explore circumstances where each is more appropriate.

Comment: I agree; it was a general observation, not an accusation.

Comment: Any thoughts? [Is CSS a better tag for the Chinese Space Station Tiangong (“Heavenly Palace”)?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1819/12102)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chinese space station is called the Tiangong ("Heavenly Palace") as seen in [this article](http://www.cnsa.gov.cn/english/n6465652/n6465653/c6811970/content.html) from the Chinese National Space Administration.

The core module that has already launched is called the Tianhe ("Harmony of the Heavens").

[image]

The rest of the modules, and details of the space station, can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiangong_space_station).

Comment: Nice diagram! It looks a lot like an FGB.

Comment: For space-word-deficient folks like myself [Zarya, also known as the **Functional Cargo Block or FGB** is the first module of the International Space Station to have been launched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarya)

Comment: @FreddieR Thank you for your answer! So while the Chinese scientists call the telescope on board the CSST in technical publications, is it *not okay* to refer to Tiangong as the CSS the way that we like to refer to the International Space Station ISS? It can't be exactly the same way since Chinese does not lend itself to acronymization, but "TG" for Tian Gong seems like a bad idea and CSS seems at least less-bad.

Comment: Looks closer to the Zvezda service module really, aka DOS stations (Salyut1-7,Mir and Zvezda). When Sino-Russian relations thawed in 1990s, several deals were done over technology and knowledge transfer to the PRC. PRC also bought tech from Ukraine which was then separated from the former Soviet Union and its space program. Mir was the leading edge project at the time so it makes sense this generation forms the base line that the PRC built from. Note the same Lyappa arm that Mir used to reorient subsequent modules (FGB based on TKS spacecraft).

Comment: @blobbymcblobby check out this picture of the ISS's FGB. http://www.russianspaceweb.com/iss-fgb-launch.html  Of course the FGB and the SM look pretty similar. I did notice the Lyappa arm, very nice.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I know, it looks similar, but the FGB was more of an autonomous module (when separated from its VA capsule), the DOS was a fully self-contained space station. Its pretty much a stretched Mir..with improvements of course. https://imgur.com/vmhlwoF

Comment: @OrganicMarble I Suppose the biggest difference and the biggest similarity is aft. The FGB design keeps the conical aft section, whereas the DOS design - around 2-3m of it - is unpressurized machinery area surrounding the transfer tunnel and retains the diameter of the pressurized operational compartment.

Comment: Thanks again! fyi I've just created the tag [tiangong-space-station](https://space.stackexchange.com/tags/tiangong-space-station/info), how does it look?