# Is there any official Chinese website where we can follow the actions of the Zhurong rover?

Tags: mars, reference-request, zhurong

[Zhurong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhurong_(rover)), China's first Mars rover, soft landed on [Utopia Planitia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_Planitia) on May 14, 2021.
Coordinates of the landing site are: [25.1⁰ N 109.7⁰ E](https://twitter.com/skyplanets/status/1393361045347966978)
The planned operational lifetime is only 90 sols.
(Why should it not work for years, like the [Opportunity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_(rover)) and [Spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_(rover)) rovers did ?)

Could we follow where it's going with images of the environment that it will traverse on an official Chinese website ?

Comment: China National Space Administration (CNSA) https://www.cast.cn/english

Comment: @A.Rumlin if that site allows viewers to "... follow the actions of the Zhurong rover" with "images of the environment that it will traverse" then it's the answer and can be posted as such!

Comment: related and potentially helpful: [Where can I find access to information provided by CNSA and Chinese scientists and reputable science authors?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46916) and possibly [What is or are the official English names for the eventual space station being built by China, and of the first module that's in orbit now?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/52023)

Comment: @uhoh we probably have no alternative in this matter. But I'm not sure. Perhaps there is a more detailed website in Chinese.
Plus, for high-speed data transmission, China has poor conditions - only one orbital repeater. Therefore, pictures and videos will rarely be transmitted and published.