# What are these Martian space-whale (or seagull) shaped features?

Tags: mars, identify-this-object, hirise

In this recently released image of CNSA's ZhuRong lander and rover
[China releases new Mars image taken by Tianwen-1 probe, CCTV (English) Article](https://english.cctv.com/2021/06/08/ARTIMUaVAyQTGX5TOhubQ3Hv210608.shtml?spm=C69523.P89601117162.EEy8zkAGlNk4.14) there are many white features scattered over the terrain:

[image: ZhuRong w/ Whales]
*(too lazy to circle them all, but you get the idea)*

**Small Aside:**
I propose they be called **'whales'** for many reasons:

- they are roughly whale sized (~tens of meters)
- people have ***literally*** used [satellite imagery](https://bioconsult-sh.de/en/news-archive/spacewhale-ii-whales-in-the-bay-of-biscay/) to [look at whales](https://business.esa.int/projects/spacewhale-ii)
- Maybe this is where the dolphins went [So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish - The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](https://youtu.be/N_dUmDBfp6k)
- They could also be interpreted as looking like *[Physeter macrocephalus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperm_whale)* (minus the whale part though...)

Enough silliness, **what are these features? Are they specific to this region of Mars (Utopia Planitia)?**

Here are snippets from a HiRISE image ([ESP_069177_2055_MIRB PDS label](https://hirise.lpl.arizona.edu/PDS/EXTRAS/RDR/ESP/ORB_069100_069199/ESP_069177_2055/ESP_069177_2055_MIRB.LBL), [low-res browser preview](https://hirise.lpl.arizona.edu/PDS/EXTRAS/RDR/ESP/ORB_069100_069199/ESP_069177_2055/ESP_069177_2055_MIRB.abrowse.jpg)) showing a few of these features in full resolution (North is up):

[image: HiRISE examples]

**Initial Observations:**

- they are all pretty well aligned East-West
- there is a large concentration of them along the bottom of a ridge (top right sub image)
- one has formed *inside* of a crater (top left, wow!)

Comment: Goodness this is a well-researched question! speaking of seeing whales from space, several can be spotted here, flippers, flukes and all: [Is it possible to see animals from space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19537/12102) and some nice looking linear-ish oriented features [here](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/10617/6031) (Earth) and [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28082/12102) (Mars).

Comment: They look like barchan dunes with erosion (the ribs of the whales)

Comment: The original Space Whale from 1965 https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/pinocchio-and-nurtle-escape-a-space-whale-in-a-scene-from-the-film-picture-id168893518 Note propulsive spout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking the [current location of the Zhurong](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/53586/whats-the-exact-location-lat-lon-of-zhurong) rover, 25.1° N and 109.7° E, as a guide to location of the region in question the [Mars Global Surveyor took this photograph in 2004](https://www.msss.com/mars_images/moc/2004/06/26/),

[image]

It shows "whale" like features on the surface of Mars, similar to the ones in your question. The location of these features is the Isidis Planitia 8.6° N, 268.2° W, which is the same as 8.6° N, 91.8° E. This is within the general location of Zhurong and thus close to the overall region associated with your first picture.

The description for the photograph states the light toned features (the "whales") as "ripple-like dunes".

This [2003 photograph](https://www.msss.com/mars_images/moc/2003/07/14/), taken by Mars Global Surveyor of the Southern Auqakuh Vallis, 27.7° N, 298.0° W (27.7° N, 62.0° E), shows "several dozen large, windblown ripples on it", which look similar to the features in your picture.

[image]

If you zoom in on the red rectangle placed over a copy of one of the pictures from your question you will see erosion gullies along the sides of the sand dune.

[image]

***In Summary:***
The "whales" are ripple-like dunes.